# Retreiving key names from a nested JSON object based upon property values

Tags: javascript

I have a nested JSON file like this...

```
{
    "A": {
        "Status": "Hard",
        "Level": "L1",
        "Capacity": "NR"
    },
    "B": {
        "Status": "Medium",
        "Level": "L2",
        "Capacity": "BR"
    },
    "C": {
        "Status": "Low",
        "Level": "L3",
        "Capacity": "SR"
    },
    "D": {
        "Status": "",
        "Level": "",
        "Capacity": "ZR"
    }
}
```

What I am looking to do is retreive the names of the key, when the **Status** and **Level** property are present or not empty. The length of the nested object can be variable.

**Desired output:**

A, B, C

I have looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631001/test-for-existence-of-nested-javascript-object-key) solution, but I am not sure how to test for the properties ? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
const obj = {
    A: {
        Status: 'Hard',
        Level: 'L1',
        Capacity: 'NR',
    },
    B: {
        Status: 'Medium',
        Level: 'L2',
        Capacity: 'BR',
    },
    C: {
        Status: 'Low',
        Level: 'L3',
        Capacity: 'SR',
    },
    D: {
        Status: '',
        Level: '',
        Capacity: 'ZR',
    },
};

const result = Object.keys(obj).filter(key => obj[key].Level && obj[key].Status);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const obj = {
    A: {
        Status: 'Hard',
        Level: 'L1',
        Capacity: 'NR',
    },
    B: {
        Status: 'Medium',
        Level: 'L2',
        Capacity: 'BR',
    },
    C: {
        Status: 'Low',
        Level: 'L3',
        Capacity: 'SR',
    },
    D: {
        Status: '',
        Level: '',
        Capacity: 'ZR',
    },
};

const result = [];

for (k in obj) {
   if (obj[k].Status && obj[k].Level) {
      result.push(k)
   }
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Very similar to @NikitaMadeev response but using a `for ... in` loop